# Is there any wrong code with my query to join table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am really confused with this codes. I have query like this

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `aIPK` AS select 
`ipbmst_fakultas`.`Kode` AS `Fakultas`,
`ipbmst_departemen`.`Kode` AS `Departemen`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` AS `NIM`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`TahunMasuk` AS `TahunMasuk`,
 `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` AS `IPK`
from (((((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister` left join `akdmst_mayor` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`MayorID` = `akdmst_mayor`.`ID`))) 
left join `ipbmst_departemen` on((`akdmst_mayor`.`DepartemenID` = `ipbmst_departemen`.`ID`))) 
left join `ipbmst_fakultas` on((`ipbmst_departemen`.`FakultasID` = `ipbmst_fakultas`.`ID`))) 
left join `ipbmst_orang` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`))) 
left join `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi` on((`akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`)))
WHERE `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` IS NOT NULL

order by NIM
LIMIT 100;
```

but "IPK" result is NULL, actually IPK has its value. What's wrong with those codes?

Here is my table structure:

```
table 1: akdmst_mahasiswamagister (ID, MahasiswaID, NIM, MayorID, TahunMasuk)
table 2: akdmst_mayor(ID, DepartemenID)
table 3: ipbmst_departemen(ID, FakultasID, DepartmenName)
table 4: ipbmst_fakultas(ID, FacultyName)
table 5: ipbmst_orang(ID, Name, NIMS2Key)
table 6: akdhis_kelanjutanstudi(ID, NIM, IPK)
```

I also have the other problem about this query. It took too much time to query the view. I thought maybe it's because table akdhis_kelanjutanstudi that consists of more than 300K data records. I have used "LIMIT 100" but still the same. could you please help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the exact problem(s) is, but your `WHERE` clause has a problem:

```
WHERE IPK IS NOT NULL
```

It is not allowed to refer to a column alias in the `WHERE` clause, because its value may not be determined yet.  Instead, you should use this:

```
WHERE akdhis_kelanjutanstudi.IPK IS NOT NULL
```

**Update:**

The parentheses you used in your original view look strange, unnecessary, and possibly wrong.  Try using the following:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW aIPK AS
SELECT t4.Kode AS Fakultas,
       t3.Kode AS Departemen,
       t1.NIM AS NIM,
       t1.TahunMasuk AS TahunMasuk,
       t6.IPK AS IPK
FROM akdmst_mahasiswamagister t1
LEFT JOIN akdmst_mayor t2
    ON t1.MayorID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN ipbmst_departemen t3
    ON t2.DepartemenID = t3.ID
LEFT JOIN ipbmst_fakultason t4
    ON t3.FakultasID = t4.ID
LEFT JOIN ipbmst_orang t5
    ON t1.NIM = t5.NIMS2Key
LEFT JOIN akdhis_kelanjutanstudi t6
    ON t6.NIM = t5.NIMS2Key
WHERE t6.IPK IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY NIM
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: yeah, I have typed the code like that, but still not working

Comment: What does `still not working` mean?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean the data fetching took so much time.

Comment: Maybe it's because table akdhis_kelanjutanstudi that consists of more than 300K data. could you please help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Running sql instead of creating algorithm is easier for testing.

In your case check the conditions in join

`` on((`akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`))) ``

also you need to change

`` WHERE `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` IS NOT NULL ``

To

`` WHERE `IPK` IS NOT NULL ``

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake in your description,

your tables are

table 1: akdhis_mahasiswamagister (ID, MahasiswaID, NIM, MayorID, TahunMasuk)
table 2: akdmst_mayor(ID, DepartemenID)
table 3: ipbmst_departemen(ID, FakultasID, DepartmenName)
table 4: ipbmst_fakultas(ID, FacultyName)
table 5: ipbmst_orang(ID, Name, NIMS2Key)
table 6: akdhis_kelanjutanstudi(ID, NIM, IPK)

but i dont see "akdhis_mahasiswamagister" table in your select

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `aIPK` AS select 
`ipbmst_fakultas`.`Kode` AS `Fakultas`,
`ipbmst_departemen`.`Kode` AS `Departemen`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` AS `NIM`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`TahunMasuk` AS `TahunMasuk`,
 `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` AS `IPK`
from (((((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister` inner join `akdmst_mayor` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`MayorID` = `akdmst_mayor`.`ID`))) 
inner join `ipbmst_departemen` on((`akdmst_mayor`.`DepartemenID` = `ipbmst_departemen`.`ID`))) 
inner join `ipbmst_fakultas` on((`ipbmst_departemen`.`FakultasID` = `ipbmst_fakultas`.`ID`))) 
inner join `ipbmst_orang` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`))) 
inner join `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi` on((`akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`)))
WHERE IPK IS NOT NULL

order by NIM
LIMIT 100;

akdhis_mahasiswamagister and akdmst_mahasiswamagister are different? may you are using wrong table, and so you have incorrect information

Comment: yes. I just made mistake in my description. I have edited my question. table 1 is akdmst_mahasiswamagister. there is no akdhis_mahasiswamagister table. So I don't use wrong table. I just made mistake on typing description