# How to join table in SQL correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table structure like this:

```
table 1: akdmst_mahasiswamagister (ID, NIM, MayorID, TahunMasuk)
table 2: akdmst_mayor(ID, Nama)
table 3: akdhis_kelanjutanstudi(ID, NIM, IPK)
```

and here is the sql code that I made:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `a1111` AS select 
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` AS `NIM`,
`akdmst_mayor`.`Nama` AS `Nama`,
`akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` AS `IPK`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`TahunMasuk` AS `Tahun Masuk`
from ((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister` left join `akdmst_mayor` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`MayorID` = `akdmst_mayor`.`ID`)))
left join `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` = `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`NIM`)));
```

but when I tried to run it, data entry result of IPK is NULL. Actually, IPK has its own value. What should I do to solve it? Thankyou

Comment: You already [asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732283/is-there-any-wrong-code-with-my-query-to-join-table/42732337?noredirect=1#comment72584064_42732337) a few hours ago.  Has anything changed?

Comment: yeah, because my question that I asked has not been solved @TimBiegeleisen